# Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

```
        $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => config('config.fb_app_id'),
            'app_secret' => config('config.fb_app_secret'),
            'default_graph_version' => 'v3.0',
        ]);
        // User info
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($access_token);
        $request = $fb->request('GET', '/me?fields=id,name');
        $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request)->getDecodedBody();
```

The above code doesn't work and it says "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist".

Really strange!! This was working fine few days back and suddenly it started throwing Errors. Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: already checked your access token with the access token debugger?

Comment: yes it shows its valid

Comment: I tried to re-authorize the app and again fetched the brand new access token but again thats also not working.The strange point is I also tested the returned new access token through Access Token Debugger Tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ and it says Valid = false So the question comes is Why Facebook Oauth returns me access token which is not valid???

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem.
Didn't notice facebook app was in developer mode.
Was working for me because I was configured as an admin in the app.

You need to add testers for the app

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem using the python SDK since yesterday on all accounts using permanent tokens.

We solved it now by [creating new tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsRek.png) in the [facebook business manager](https://business.facebook.com/settings/system-users). Maybe this readme also provides some guidance https://github.com/mara/facebook-ads-performance-downloader

Comment: Yes but it doesn't makes any sense because If I am again reauthorize the app then the returned access token should work but instead its not working so it means FB is providing me wrong access token.

Comment: Sorry that this did not help. I got the same error message and it worked for me. So I thought it could also work for you.

Comment: no need for sorry I appreciate your support the only point is lets say if any one me or you or any person wants to authorize the app but FB provides token which doesn't work at all,  is it fair?? And also the strange point is if I make use of FB Graph API explorer then the token generated fine over there.So not sure whats going wrong with Facebook ??

Comment: This was a bug from FB  and https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/194772814474841/ and its resolved now!

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for it, you should visit your App's Alerts page first to check if there is some issue with your account:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<APP_ID>/alerts/inbox/?business_id=<BUSINESS_ID>

> You cannot access live data if your application is in development mode.

The Alerts look like this:
[image]